# Dialogflow webhook gives error response in AoG Simulator when response contains baicCard

Tags: python, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I am receiving this response from webhook but dialogflow does not response with basicCard instead gives the following error.

MalformedResponse

Webhook error (206).

I want to know that if there is any problem with the response i need to improve.

The AoG simulator works without basicCard in response.

Thanks...

```
{
  "conversationToken": "[\"follow_up_user_email\",\"follow_up_user_name\",\"follow_up_user_query\"]",
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [
    {
      "inputPrompt": {
        "richInitialPrompt": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "This is a Basic Card:"
              }
            },
            {
              "basicCard": {
                "title": "Card Title",
                "image": {
                  "url": "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png",
                  "accessibilityText": "Google Logo"
                },
                "buttons": [
                  {
                    "title": "Button Title",
                    "openUrlAction": {
                      "url": "https://www.google.com"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "imageDisplayOptions": "WHITE"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "possibleIntents": [
        {
          "intent": "assistant.intent.action.TEXT"
        },
        {
          "intent": "526ffb44-6bcb-412a-b8eb-09343ea90345"
        },
        {
          "intent": "ead593af-950f-42ae-9c67-9a0565bc1a2d"
        },
        {
          "intent": "cd6abbe2-ac77-4a76-a0e2-4819de881d1f"
        }
      ],
      "speechBiasingHints": [
        "$user_query",
        "$admission_query",
        "$facility",
        "$admission_type"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "code": 14,
      "message": "Webhook error (206)"
    },
    "queryMatchInfo": {
      "queryMatched": true,
      "intent": "526ffb44-6bcb-412a-b8eb-09343ea90345",
      "parameterNames": [
        "email"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my DEBUG Tab Log:

```
{
  "response": "Soongsil guide isn't responding right now. Try again soon.",
  "expectUserResponse": false,
  "conversationToken": "EroCS2w1M2...",
  "audioResponse": "//NExAASWK...",
  "debugInfo": {
    "assistantToAgentDebug": {
      "curlCommand": "curl -v 'https://api.api.ai/api/integrations/google?token=5aa622c9340f4609aefe4ab4b4b011c0' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Google-Actions-API-Version: 2' -H 'Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjQ2M2ZlNDgwYzNjNTgzOWJiYjE1ODYxZTA4YzMyZDE4N2ZhZjlhNTYiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiJ1bmlhc3Npc3RhbnRib3QiLCJuYmYiOjE1NDM4MzIzNzUsImlhdCI6MTU0MzgzMjY3NSwiZXhwIjoxNTQzODMyNzk1LCJqdGkiOiIxNTIyNzlmOWZjYjZmZTE3ODZmYTM0MjQzY2UzYjQ0MzhhZDkxOTBmIn0.EjfBv3tI-_YKcQjBOpDySERHScYOtPrLUPM0TWo23MVt53TV0cNaKzFMSAoQ4lw22WEBI_C2Ghz38W5QbmXLRMMs0OZQaMwpBtGM2vsaEDiuLnoOGTeEgH_J4JYTu1hjufPG6mJY0cY-Mr6CGV7Y9WlzgOBBLJ4Qhf-SnnQaRTKD2yB4yiF_16HzFk46caoo9Ym3eOZd-9ZkQ9x_MvmfOK_WR0ldUp8BocguBeTB7oqnMc44nnajgnY6BIWCm9dzxpFdLvSUCoucOUbkn3WhM6tYnqua7pIa9W6ew75w_ph9-6MxMvI-OGr1u39IT9pNN7Ojz9NRLq6u7kZyJCRdFg'  -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)' -X POST -d '{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"ABwppHEwwiuoxAL916ji--u4JNvKc-BhNjLB63JRTRr80z7Hj5m7mwLtLEYdMWXBj2DXlPh6nzdlWOZxlBoA\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2018-12-03T10:18:52Z\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"ABwppHFJrjyCFEfsXlTB1yNk6JzpS3TuXZv_2OKga8jOJJFfl6QxF310U8i_LMHr-8tjQca_5N5Lphbiw39U\",\"type\":\"ACTIVE\",\"conversationToken\":\"[\\\"follow_up_user_email\\\",\\\"follow_up_user_name\\\",\\\"follow_up_user_query\\\"]\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.TEXT\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"KEYBOARD\",\"query\":\"muzamil.sw10@gmail.com\"}],\"arguments\":[{\"name\":\"text\",\"rawText\":\"muzamil.sw10@gmail.com\",\"textValue\":\"muzamil.sw10@gmail.com\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"}]}],\"requestType\":\"SIMULATOR\"}'",
      "assistantToAgentJson": "{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"ABwppHEwwiuoxAL916ji--u4JNvKc-BhNjLB63JRTRr80z7Hj5m7mwLtLEYdMWXBj2DXlPh6nzdlWOZxlBoA\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2018-12-03T10:18:52Z\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"ABwppHFJrjyCFEfsXlTB1yNk6JzpS3TuXZv_2OKga8jOJJFfl6QxF310U8i_LMHr-8tjQca_5N5Lphbiw39U\",\"type\":\"ACTIVE\",\"conversationToken\":\"[\\\"follow_up_user_email\\\",\\\"follow_up_user_name\\\",\\\"follow_up_user_query\\\"]\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.TEXT\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"KEYBOARD\",\"query\":\"muzamil.sw10@gmail.com\"}],\"arguments\":[{\"name\":\"text\",\"rawText\":\"muzamil.sw10@gmail.com\",\"textValue\":\"muzamil.sw10@gmail.com\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"}]}],\"requestType\":\"SIMULATOR\"}",
      "delegatedRequest": {
        "delegatedRequest": ""
      }
    },
    "agentToAssistantDebug": {
      "agentToAssistantJson": "{\"conversationToken\":\"[\\\"follow_up_user_email\\\",\\\"follow_up_user_name\\\",\\\"follow_up_user_query\\\"]\",\"expectUserResponse\":true,\"expectedInputs\":[{\"inputPrompt\":{\"richInitialPrompt\":{\"items\":[{\"simpleResponse\":{\"textToSpeech\":\"This is a Basic Card:\"}},{\"basicCard\":{\"title\":\"Card Title\",\"image\":{\"url\":\"https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png\",\"accessibilityText\":\"Google Logo\"},\"buttons\":[{\"title\":\"Button Title\",\"openUrlAction\":{\"url\":\"https://www.google.com\"}}],\"imageDisplayOptions\":\"WHITE\"}}]}},\"possibleIntents\":[{\"intent\":\"assistant.intent.action.TEXT\"},{\"intent\":\"526ffb44-6bcb-412a-b8eb-09343ea90345\"},{\"intent\":\"ead593af-950f-42ae-9c67-9a0565bc1a2d\"},{\"intent\":\"cd6abbe2-ac77-4a76-a0e2-4819de881d1f\"}],\"speechBiasingHints\":[\"$user_query\",\"$admission_query\",\"$facility\",\"$admission_type\"]}],\"responseMetadata\":{\"status\":{\"code\":14,\"message\":\"Webhook error (206)\"},\"queryMatchInfo\":{\"queryMatched\":true,\"intent\":\"526ffb44-6bcb-412a-b8eb-09343ea90345\",\"parameterNames\":[\"email\"]}}}",
      "delegatedResponse": {
        "delegatedResponse": ""
      }
    },
    "sharedDebugInfoList": [
      {
        "name": "ResponseValidation",
        "debugInfo": "",
        "subDebugEntryList": [
          {
            "name": "MalformedResponse",
            "debugInfo": "Webhook error (206).",
            "subDebugEntryList": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "visualResponse": {
    "visualElementsList": [
      {
        "displayText": {
          "content": "Soongsil guide isn't responding right now. Try again soon."
        }
      }
    ],
    "suggestionsList": [],
    "agentLogoUrl": ""
  },
  "clientError": 0,
  "is3pResponse": 1,
  "clientOperationList": []
}
```

Comment: Can you update your answer with log where you are getting the error

Answer (score 0):

check the DEBUG and ERROR tabs in the simulator to see if you find more detailed messages. In most cases you need to have Suggestion chips after the card.